# Request mod-level synonyms be created for [spaying] / [neutering] / [fixing]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

We have the desexing tag, which someone set-up a while back as the go-to tag for this sort of thing.

Unfortunately, while it is the correct term, "desexing" is not the word the average person uses when referring to this process.

Over my time editing questions, I encountered questions tagged using variants of spay / neuter / fixing, which are all covered by "desexing".  They were all re-tagged with that term.  This has the unfortunate side-effect of eliminating the possibility of non-moderators being capable of creating synonyms.

Due to the frequency of re-tagging, there will not be a build-up of incorrect tags for quite a while.

I suggest the following synonym list be created and applied via moderation, and poll the community for any additional:

- fixing -> desexing
- spaying -> desexing
- neutering -> desexing

Comment: castration -> desexing as well

Comment: do you have to include all variations like spay, fix, and neuter?

Comment: No. Once you start typing the first letters of a synonym, the suggested word appears.  Put the longer word in and you cover all bases.

Comment: but wait... does a ovarian sparing spay or a "Zeutered" dog count as "Desexing"? It would seem not :-)

Comment: what about a uteran sparing spay? I haven't asked the question yet but I will this weekend if nobody gets to it first.

Comment: I dont know what that is; The description would be adjusted yo account for temporary prevention as well.

Comment: Yah very true. I was only meaning that people might not think of either of those procedures as Desexing because they both leave at least some of the hormones in place. Temporary prevention would cause the same confusion. But I think with a few more questions we'll get it worked out. Probably trying to solve it to early at this point.

Comment: It is considered a chemical casteation so yes it would

Comment: I've merged the tags. For basic purposes, I think chemical measures can be accommodated by the tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given the reworked question, I think having a moderator make these synonyms is a good idea.  It will avoid help to avoid confusion, and keep the tags from being created without the link.

Comment: Yeah, those tags are there all right, but since there is no questions under them it is impossible to post answers and thus gain the needed 5 reputation points to suggest a synonym. So, this leaves moderators the only ones who can synonymize those tags.

Comment: LO AND BEHOLD - someone didn't use the d-tag: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2407/what-are-the-benefits-and-drawbacks-of-using-zeuterin-or-a-product-like-it-for-n

Comment: Totally unfamiliar with the product, can't answer it :( ... wait, that didn't stop me from answering this http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/789/what-signs-indicate-a-dog-has-been-baited-with-poison/2086#2086 poison bait question :)

Comment: I agree, I'll try and clean that up tonight.